# parse error: parse error

Tags: php, parse-error

I was messing around with the output echo that gave the results of the query trying to figure out how to make the dog breed bold and now I am getting this

> -Parse error: parse error in /Library/WebServer/Documents/dogs.php on line 22

I am pulling my hair out on this, if anyone can help with either the parse error or how to make the dog breeds bold I would be in your debt.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT b.dogbreed ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DogName) FROM Names WHERE dogId=b.dogId ) as Dognames from breeds b";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo . $row["dogbreed"].  " - " . $row["Dognames"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

</html>
```

Comment: And which is line 22 in this code containing **21** lines??? We are not always clairvoyant!

Comment: `echo '<span style="font-weight:bold"' . $row["dogbreed"].  "</span> - " . $row["Dognames"]. "<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo . $row["dogbreed"].  " - " . $row["Dognames"]. "<br>";
```

Take out the . after echo:

```
echo $row["dogbreed"] . " - " . $row["Dognames"] . "<br>";
```

Comment: ugh that did it , defeated by a . thank you!!

Comment: my pleasure, mind marking this answer as correct? ^__^

Answer (score 0):

The tag you would be looking for in html to make it bold is this:

```
<strong>Text</strong>
```

Otherwise, if you could include more of your code and the lines, it would be of better help with the current error.

Comment: I get the idea of the <strong> tag but in this case it is $row["dogbreed"], where would I put the strong tag

Comment: As suggested by @Mohammed Akhtar Zuberi :
    echo "<strong>" . $row ["dogbreed"] . "</strong>"

Comment: awesome thank you guys so much

Answer (score 0):

To make any text bold in `echo`, simply add `echo "<strong>" . $row ["dogbreed"] . "</strong>"`.

This way you can make any part of text bold.

Comment: Hope this answer clarifies.